# Stripe elements and 3d secure

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have recently begun working with Stripe elements. Now I need to have it complete 3d secure and then save the customer to Stripe and the customer token to my database. I know how to make a customer, but have never previously worked with 3d secure and sources.

So my question is: How do I do I check if a source can be used with three d secure? Using API v3 in my script.

Here is the script I'm using after having set my API key previously.

```js
<script>
    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
    var style = {
      base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        lineHeight: '18px',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4'
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#fa755a',
        iconColor: '#fa755a'
      }
    };

    // Create an instance of the card Element.
    var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
    card.mount('#card-element');
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
          displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
          displayError.textContent = '';
        }
     });

  // Create a source or display an error when the form is submitted.
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createSource(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the source to your server
        stripeSourceHandler(result.source);
      }
    });
  });
  function stripeSourceHandler(source) {

      // Insert the source ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeSource');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', source.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

I know PHP fairly well and would like to use that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is full documentation for integrating 3DS with Stripe here : https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure

As for your direct question, to check if a source supports 3DS or not, you would check the value of the source's `card.three_d_secure` attribute: https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure#check-requirement

Comment: Okay. Follow up question. How do i check stripes json response??

Comment: Which JSON response are you referring to?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Is it possible to use 3d secure with server side programming in asp.net.

Comment: Not directly, 3D Secure requires the customer to directly authorise a payment with their bank's website, so you need to have at least some frontend code to have the user do that.

Comment: @karllekko Can I manage 3DS via Stripe invoice? So that whenever `invoice.payment_action_required` webhook triggered, I will send invoice url to customer via email, customer will authorize it, and I will get inform via webhook `invoice.payment_succeeded` about payment completion?